# highcharts : set title on exporting

Tags: export, highcharts

I'm looking a way to:

- hide title on the HTML page result
- show title on the highcharts graph when I export it (PDF,PNG,JPEG or print)

I don't know how to proceed. There is someone able to help me?

Answer (score 16):

You can define this parameter in exporting.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions

http://jsfiddle.net/BdHJM/

```
exporting:{
            chartOptions:{
                title: {
                    text:'aaaaa'
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: This doesn't work in your fiddle. The chart is exported with no title.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  But it doesn't seem to be working for printing, only for export to file.  Is there a way to get it to work for printing as well?

Comment: Unforunately not possible, you can consider how to prepare custom print function in javascript, and then call in menu items.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Can you please edit the answer to specify that its not for Print. ?

Answer (score 3):

put this function in your document ready function below is a code for changing highcharts print prototype and just for the patch or to make it work put rangeSelector option in your exporting and set it to false as mentioned below you can set it to your needs in future

```
     Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'print', function (proceed) {

                    var applyMethod = function (whatToDo, margin) {
                    this.extraTopMargin = margin;
                    this.resetMargins();
                    this.setSize(this.container.clientWidth , this.container.clientHeight , false);

                    this.setTitle(null, { text: 'SET TITLE HERE' :'});

                    this.rangeSelector.zoomText[whatToDo]();
                    $.each(this.rangeSelector.buttons, function (index, button) {
                        button[whatToDo]();
                    });
                };
                if (this.rangeSelector) {
                    var extraMargin = this.extraTopMargin;
                    applyMethod.apply(this, ['hide', null]);
                    var returnValue = proceed.call(this);
                    applyMethod.apply(this, ['show', extraMargin]);
                    this.setTitle(null, { text: '' });
                } else {
                    return proceed.call(this);
                    this.setTitle(null, { text: '' });
                    this.yAxis[0].setExtremes();
                }                       }


    });
```

and in chart option set this (change it according to you need to, i am just putting my code for reference
)

```
     exporting: {
            scale: 1,
            sourceWidth: 1600,
            sourceHeight: 900,

            chartOptions: {
                rangeSelector: {
                    enabled: false
            },
    }
```